# Why django can be tested without running server?

Tags: python, django, testing

I want to test the reachability of home page of a demo app.

So I do this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class TestHomePageView(TestCase):
    def test_reachable_home(self):
        response = self.client.get('/home/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

and the `views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

`home.html` is a simple one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hi, circleci and django
</body>
</html>
```

and `urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from demo_app.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', home_view)
]
```

It's a really simple demo app.

What I am curious is "Why I can test the status code without running django server?"
Just simply `$ python manage.py test` without `$ python manage.py runserver`

and get the test result:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.011s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any idea or suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Because testing software does all it needs to do, with regards to setup and teardown, so that it can run its tests.

Comment: How can django run server and test then down server so fast?
Or it just simulate the whole progress?

Comment: Forget my question, I find the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing allows you to modify your code with more confidence: tests are ok, you modify your code, if tests are still ok, then, you didn't break anything.

Thus, you want to be able to execute your tests often and fast, so you can modify your code more easily, with more confidence.

Framworks and languages provide means of testing that are the lighter possible, so tests are more flexible and runs faster.

Also, you want to test your code, not others, if your tests runs through http, you also test your http server.

Moreover, HTTP, is a transport protocol, we don't need a transport protocol to provide arguments to functions, to check it behaves as intended.

To sum up, you want to be able to run your test often, the fastest it is, the more you are able to run your tests, plus, you want to test only your code, not the code of your webserver.

Comment: I would also link [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) which explains the Django test client in more detail.

Comment: Agreed, my answer is very generic, not specific to django !

Comment: Got your point, but I want to know more specific way django did. Does django simulate the environment? Or, it can just handle the server up, tested then server down?

Comment: Another question is that can other frameworks be tested without running server?

Comment: The linked documents, specific to django mentions this: The test client does not require the Web server to be running. In fact, it will run just fine with no Web server running at all! That’s because it avoids the overhead of HTTP and deals directly with the Django framework. This helps make the unit tests run quickly.

Comment: @rongson it depends on the framework, but generally, tests tools are made to run with the most simple setup possible, subtracting the more layer possiblem. Are you asking specifically for another framework ? which one ?

Comment: @user801247,@dirkgroten Finally understand it, thank you!! Maybe Laravel?